# S2S picklist value missing on publish

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

We have an issue in our S2S connection. Our source org has published the PicklistField1, that contains Value1, Value2, Value3. Target org admin has reported that he has successfully subscribed to the field, but he sees only Value1 and Value2, but not Value3.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We did not track the roots of the issue, but following has helped:

1. Unpublish the field
2. Wait 1 minute
3. Publish it back

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA